# /Users/chingun/.zshrc:source:116: no such file or directory: /usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.shexport

Tags: macos, terminal

The following error occurs when I open my terminal:

Last login: Fri Jun 18 11:10:15 on ttys000
/Users/chingun/.zshrc:source:116: no such file or directory: /usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.shexport

[Terminal Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO96T.png)

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify [deepakchethan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68028352/11365812) answer, you are exporting another path in your `.zshrc` file and there needs to be a space before that path is exported like below.

You probably have this:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"export PATH="/usr/local/opt/{another path}:$PATH"
```

You need to have this:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" export PATH="/usr/local/opt/{another path}:$PATH"
```

Notice there is no space before the `export PATH=` and therefore it is being concatenated. Took a while for me to notice this also.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the `.zshrc` file. Open the file `/Users/chingun/.zshrc` and in the line 116 you need to change the file path of `nvm.sh` from `/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.shexport` to `/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Go to .zshrc

and delete the export from the end of the line

```bash
/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.shexport

/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh
```

You probably have used an echo statement for another script which exported values inline, instead of a new line.

That should fix the issue